# Creating instagram-like view (table/grid)

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Here]

I am trying to create the table/grid you see just below 'SHARE' with facebook, twitter, tumblr text..

I don't wish to add any images.

I tried taking a relativeLayout with TableLayout.. creating tables etc... I was able to get similar table/grid with sharp edges though. If I use a custom shape and use rounded corners, the outside box would be round but the inner textviews would still remain square. Its all a mess up, please guide me with this. Thanks..

Here's what I could manage:
[image: myimage]

Please help, thanks!

Comment: instead of table layout, try relative layout with buttons for fb, twitter, foursqare etc. each button with weight 1 so that it occupies same width on every row

Comment: Hmm, let me try that now. It sounds like a good idea. Not sure how to make it work.